# Alternative to Thread.sleep() for for better performance

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, design-patterns, concurrency

I have developed a REST service. The service have one Api endpoint: v1/customer. This Api
does two things:

1. It executes the business logic in main thread
2. Spawns a child thread to perform the non critical DB writes. The main thread returns response to client immediately, whereas the child thread write to DB asynchronously.

As both of the these operations Step 1 and 2 are not synchronous, it is becoming increasingly challenging to test both of these scenario.
Let's say when I try to test the API. I am testing two things (api response and DB writes)
As the DB writes happen async fashion. I have to use a Thread.sleep(2000). This process is not scalable and doesn't yield right result. Soon I might have 1000 test cases to run and the total time to run all these testcases will increase enormously.
What design technique shall I use to test the DB writes keeping performance and execution time in mind.

Comment: I doubt that spawning a thread for every request is a good thing because you have unbound threads in your system and this can lead to all kinds of problems. Probably better to use a threadpool. Using a fixed timeout is also problematic because it can lead to false positives: so a test fails even though the change will appear eventually.  One way to deal with this is to have a single thread in the test class that is shared between all tests and checks for each of the tests if the desired state is set at an interval of e.g. 100ms. And you can give a long timeout for the test e.g. 30s.

Comment: If I am understanding your description correctly, the real problem here is the design / architecture of your REST service.  For a start, doing the database writes asynchronously sounds wrong, and having a single (?) main thread for business logic is wrong.

Comment: But one way to deal with testing would be to use mocks to test the business logic handling and the database separately.

Comment: Your title is unclear and somewhat off-track from your question. I suggest you rewrite to summarize your actual question.

Comment: Don't use `sleep()` to coordinate the activity of threads. If thread T needs the result of some task that thread U performs "aysnchronously," then you should use some thread-to-thread signalling means (Semaphore, CompletableFuture, BlockingQueue, Exchanger,...) that allows thread T to either (A) wait until the _exact moment_ when thread U signals that the task is complete and the result is ready, or (B) not wait at all if the task was already completed.

Comment: Don't test routines that directly call `sleep()`. (This is another good reason for not using `sleep()` at all.) If there's some reason why a thread absolutely _must_ sleep (e.g., in order to schedule real-time activities), then you can have it call some `o.sleep()` method, where `o` is an object that can be [_mocked_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double). Then, your tests can verify that the routine calls `o.sleep(n)` when it is supposed to do, but without _actually_ sleeping for `n` milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change your api design if possible. One possible solution could be to have your first api call respond with http 202 accepted and return some kind of job ID to the client. With this job ID the client could check the progress via a GET on another endpoint. This would allow you to have polling in your test without hardcoding some sleep values.

Here is a example that shows the process in a bit more detail.

https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/